# How to detect MDIChild if the child is just a duplicate of a form?

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I have `frm_Child` and `frm_Parent`, I set the `isMDIContainer` of `frm_Parent` to `true`

Within the frm_Parent I have 2 buttons

1. `btn_Create` - to create another `mdi child`
2. `btn_Detect` - to detect active `mdi Child` `(When I say active it means that I set my focused on it)`

**frm_Parent Code:**

```
Public Class frm_Parent

   Public my_variable As String

   Private Sub btn_create_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_create.Click
      my_variable += 1
      Call New frm_Child() With {.MdiParent = Me}.Show()
   End Sub

   Private Sub btn_Detect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Detect.Click
      'Code to detect active mdi child
   End Sub

End Class
```

Then I have frm_Child and within that I have `label1.text`, the value of `label1.text` will automatically get upon `form_load` and it depends entirely on the value of `my_variable` on `frm_Parent`

**frm_Child code:**

```
Public Class frm_Child

   Private Sub frm_Child_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      Label1.Text = frm_Parent.my_variable
   End Sub

End Class
```

Sample screenshot if I create 4 new frm_Child

[image]

**Question:** How do I programmatically detect the active mdi child and show the label1.text to messagebox? `(note: active mean that I set my on it.)`

I've tried something like this,

```
Private Sub btn_Detect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Detect.Click
    'Code to detect active mdi child
    Dim activeChild As Form = me.ActiveMdiChild
    MsgBox(activeChild.label1.text)
End Sub
```

Also this, I've modify [the example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984347(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
Private Sub btn_Detect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Detect.Click
    'Code to detect active mdi child
    Dim activeChild As Form = Me.ActiveMdiChild

    ' If there is an active child form, find the active control, which
    ' in this example should be a RichTextBox.
    If (Not activeChild Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            Dim theLabel As Label = CType(activeChild.ActiveControl, Label)
            MsgBox(theLabel.Text)
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("You need to select an active form.")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something so I'm adding this as a comment rather than an answer.  The parent form has an `ActiveMdiChild` property.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I am still not sure because I also tried to put `Dim activeChild As Form = me.ActiveMdiChild` then `MsgBox(activeChild.label1.text)` so I can get the active child `label1.text` but it's not working?

Comment: The `ActiveMdiChild` property is type `Form`.  It should be obvious that it has to be because that child can be any type of form.  Does the `Form` class have a member named `label1`?  If you want a member of a specific type then cast as that type.

Comment: As for getting the active control, how can a `Label` be the active control?  Ever seen a `Label` get focus?

Comment: @jmcilhinney oh thanks for pointing that out. I change the label to a textbox and it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum up the comments in an answer, you need to get the child form via the `ActiveMdiChild` property of the parent and cast it as the appropriate type in order to be able to access members of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you should pass the "my_variable" value to the **Constructor** of your child form, but going with jmcilhinney's advice of **casting**, you should grab it like this (instead of using the default instance):

```
Private Sub frm_Child_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim parent As frm_Parent = DirectCast(Me.MdiParent, frm_Parent)
    Me.Label1.Text = parent.my_variable
End Sub
```

Similarly, here's how you'd cast the MdiChild and grab the Label in your "detect" button:

```
Private Sub btn_Detect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Detect.Click
    If Not IsNothing(Me.ActiveMdiChild) Then
        Dim child As frm_Child = DirectCast(Me.ActiveMdiChild, frm_Child)
        MessageBox.Show(child.Label1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, if you're going to have different **types** of MdiChildren, then you'll either have to put in extra checks and cast to the correct type, or use an **Interface** that all the children implement and cast to that instead.